# jQuery move div into another div inside same parent

Tags: jquery, html, append, move, appendto

```
<div class="events">

 <div class="single_event">

 <div class="div1">
  <div class="moveMe"><img src="example.img" /></div>
 </div>

 <div class="div2">
  <!-- .moveMe targets here -->
 </div>

</div><!-- end .single-event -->


<div class="single_event">

 <div class="div1">
  <div class="moveMe"><img src="example.img" /></div>
 </div>

 <div class="div2">
  <!-- .moveMe targets here -->
 </div>

</div><!-- end .single-event --> 

</div><!-- end .events -->
```

For each .moveMe inside every .single_event, i want to move the entire element(.moveMe) into div2. Have been working on this for a while now and i just can't get it to work..

Anyone got a clue?

Here's the website: http://livefixtures.co.uk
* notice, i'm working on it live so it might look weird.

I want to move .wd-event-channels to .wd-event-content.

i tried this with jQuery:

```
$('.wd-event-channels').appendTo(function(){
 return $(this).parent().find('.wd-event-content');
});
```

By executing parent twice, i'm on wd-event-wrap level, and then i can choose the corresponding target div (.wd-event-content). Important is that the div is moved within the same wd-event.

Comment: Please post your jquery code so far.

Comment: Can you include what you have already tried please. Who knows. You might be closer than you think

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.div2').append(function() {
    return $(this).prev('.div1').find('.moveMe');
});
```